# Create File object from image url

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file

I am trying to give a value an file input field value by file url, but it does not work. ($preview_url is PHP variable with image url)

```
<input type="file" id="preview" name="preview" accept="image/*" required value="<?php echo $preview_url; ?>">
```

I tried to create an object of type File, but this also does not work.

```
const previewUploadButton = document.getElementById('preview');
previewUploadButton.file = new File([''], '<?php $preview_url; ?>', {
    'image/jpeg'
});
```

How can I create an object of type File or FileList from an image URL? Or is it possible to solve this problem in another way?

Comment: What is the goal here? Where and how are you going to use that file?

Comment: I am trying to create a simple information editing page, where all the values ​​are pre-taken from the database.

Comment: Yes, but what exactly are you going to do with that file? Upload it back to your server?

Comment: The user can select another image or leave this one and send it to the database.